# Dark Mode Function

Tags: javascript, darkmode

I created a dark mode function that allows me to use local storage to "save" the last selected preference the user chose by clicking on an icon even if they go to different pages within the site, refresh, close, etc. What I can't figure out is how I can add an if statement so that the icon will also chance its "src" into a different png file when the "darkmode" is enabled and then switch back to another icon when it is disabled. If anyone could help me with this I would very much appreciate it.

```
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 

const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('#dark-mode-toggle');

const enableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.add('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}

if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
  enableDarkMode();
}


darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
  
  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();

  } else {  
    disableDarkMode(); 
  }
});

const scrollBtn = document.getElementById("scroll_up")

    scrollBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.documentElement.scrollTop= 0;
    });
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify the `src` attribute, like so:

```js
const enableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.add('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
  darkModeToggle.src = "./images/darkToggle.svg"; // replace the path according to YOUR directory structure
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
  darkModeToggle.src = "./images/lightToggle.svg"; // replace the path according to YOUR directory structure
}
```